# Confluent cloud S3 sink connector - custom object name for S3 Objects

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My `Kafka` messages would contain UUID which will be the identifier for all future communications. I configured an `s3-sink-connector` for my topic which is writing all the ingested messages into my S3 bucket with default naming convention (i.e. `<topic>+<kafkaPartition>+<startOffset>.<format>`). With these names, it is difficult to identify the corresponding s3 object for a given message UUID.

Is there a way to define the S3 object name with one of the field values of the original message?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FieldPartitioner` to create paths containing `s3://bucket/uuid=xxx-yyy-zzz/topic.format` files

Comment: uuid is one of the fields of my message, can you please let me know how to set it as part of the path?

Comment: Have you tried to find the documentation for `partitioner.class` or `FieldPartitioner` property of the S3 sink?